# Is there any risk involved allowing users to create their own URL's

Tags: url

I am about to launch a eCommerce platform where users have their own shop URL based on the username IE my username on stack is NoobSkie so I would access my shop at

`www.example.com/noobskie/shop`

Is there any thing that could go wrong with this setup with people trying to manipulate URL's?

Comment: strings are not a threat - what you *do* with those strings can be a threat ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the validation that is in place regarding the username.

If you already

- whitelist the characters in the username to alphanumeric only
- restrict the maximum size of the usernames
- ensure username unicity
- ensure that no username can match existing url's (depends on your site, maybe this is not needed.. It is if you have for example something like `/default/shop` or `/welcome/shop`)

, I don't see much of a risk :)

Comment: Along with the username validation, same or similar validation should be in place when parsing the URL before doing anything with the string especially database lookups.

Comment: This was my hunch originally I was looking into facebooks username's and it's along the same lines

Answer (score 2):

Do you let users customise their shop? If they can edit HTML they may be able to include JavaScript, which would allow a cross-site scripting attack. Because of this, many services instead have URLs like: http://noobskie.example.com/

Answer (score 2):

Since Let's Encrypt lets server admins validate the domain using a `/.well-known/acme-challenge` endpoint, a malicious user could register a username `.well-known` and set up a shop with the name `acme-challenge`.

It is impossible to know all validation mechanisms out there, so I would opt for the solution already proposed by @paj28, which is to give users a URL in the form of `$username.example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that people can't commit identity theft using your system or create spoof accounts. What I mean is something like

example.com/amazon

People might use third party brand names for example. This is unlawful in many countries and can get you in trouble accordingly.